# Dropped and lost Vitamin D3: affect on dog?

Tags: dogs

My wife dropped her dose of Vitamin D3, one capsule 2000iu. we can't find it, but for sure, our 3 yo Dachshund (13 lbs, give or take) will find it and eat it.

Any adverse effects we should watch for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Vitamin D3 LD

You will start to see side-effects at a dose of 0.1mg/kg and above, let's do a bit of math.

Your dog weighs approximately 5.9kg

5.9kg x 0.1mg =  0.59mg

Each mg of Vitamin D3 contains 40,000IU

Your dog would need to ingest 23,600IU in order to reach a toxic level. With a lost dose of 2,000IU I would not worry.

### Signs to look out for

- Vomiting
- Lethargy
- Increased thirst
- Increased urination
- Seizures
- Dark tarry in stools

If you have any concerns about your pet ingesting a toxin there are some helplines available as well.

[ASPCA Poison Control](https://www.aspca.org/pet-care/animal-poison-control)

[Pet Poison Helpline](http://www.petpoisonhelpline.com/)

([Source 1](https://www.merckvetmanual.com/toxicology/rodenticide-poisoning/cholecalciferol)) ([Source 2](http://www.pethealthnetwork.com/dog-health/dog-toxins-poisons/vitamin-d-poisoning)) ([Source 3](https://dietarysupplementdatabase.usda.nih.gov/ingredient_calculator/help.php))

Comment: Normally I like to leave a question open for a week or so, to help promote answers. But...